# How do I use jspdf on my Blazor Server App project?

Tags: javascript, blazor, jspdf

I want to be able to export the data from my ReportDetails.razor page to PDF using jsPDF. However, I am getting an error that jspdf is not defined. Here is my code that uses the exportPDF below:

**ReportDetails.razor**

```
    private async Task ExportAsPDF()
    {
        try
        {
            // Call JavaScript function to export PDF
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("exportPDF", update);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error exporting PDF: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**exportPDF.js**

```
export function exportPDF(update) {
    console.log("JavaScript function exportPDF invoked!");

    // Create a new jsPDF instance
    const pdf = new new jspdf.jsPDF();

    // Set document properties (optional)
    pdf.setProperties({
        title: 'Emergency Report',
        subject: 'Incident details',
        author: 'BDRRMO Admin',
        keywords: 'emergency, report',
    });

    // Add content to the PDF
    var content = `
    Report Details:
    Reported By: ${update.Email}
    Date & Time: ${update.DateTime}
    Description: ${update.Description}
    Location: ${update.Location}
    Status: ${update.Status}
    Remarks: ${update.Remarks}
    Responder: ${update.Responder}
    Emergency Medical Responder: ${update.MedicalResponder}
    Time of Departure: ${update.Departure}
    Time of Arrival at the scene: ${update.Arrival}
    Total Response Time: ${update.ResponseTime}
    For Vehicle Accident, the patient is: ${update.VehicleAccident}
    For Fire Incident, the patient is: ${update.Fire}
    For Crime Incident, the patient is: ${update.Crime}
  `;

    pdf.text(content, 10, 10);

    // Save the PDF or open it in a new tab
    pdf.save('Emergency_Report.pdf');

    console.log("PDF generation completed successfully!");
}
```

I have already imported the jspdf javascript library to my _Host.hmtl and also my javasrcipt file.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/PDFExport.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try adding your function to the `window` object. `window.exportPDF = function(update) { }`

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix the typo. The solution was removing export before the function on line 1 and also fixing the typo.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there's a syntax error in your exportPDF.js file when creating a new instance of jspdf. The issue is in the following line:

```
 const pdf = new new jspdf.jsPDF();
```

You have an extra new keyword. It should be:

```
const pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF();
```

Here's the corrected version of your exportPDF.js file:

```
export function exportPDF(update) {
    console.log("JavaScript function exportPDF invoked!");

    // Create a new jsPDF instance
    const pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF();

    // Set document properties (optional)
    pdf.setProperties({
        title: 'Emergency Report',
        subject: 'Incident details',
        author: 'BDRRMO Admin',
        keywords: 'emergency, report',
    });

    // Add content to the PDF
    var content = `
    Report Details:
    Reported By: ${update.Email}
    Date & Time: ${update.DateTime}
    Description: ${update.Description}
    Location: ${update.Location}
    Status: ${update.Status}
    Remarks: ${update.Remarks}
    Responder: ${update.Responder}
    Emergency Medical Responder: ${update.MedicalResponder}
    Time of Departure: ${update.Departure}
    Time of Arrival at the scene: ${update.Arrival}
    Total Response Time: ${update.ResponseTime}
    For Vehicle Accident, the patient is: ${update.VehicleAccident}
    For Fire Incident, the patient is: ${update.Fire}
    For Crime Incident, the patient is: ${update.Crime}
  `;

    pdf.text(content, 10, 10);

    // Save the PDF or open it in a new tab
    pdf.save('Emergency_Report.pdf');

    console.log("PDF generation completed successfully!");
}
```

After making this change, your code should work without the "jspdf is not defined" error.